# Display div elements inline in a grid_12 class with 960grid

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I am having grid_4 for a navigation (user input) and then grid_12 for the main window. When I return a PartialView to the Content div, which renders 2 divs, and one of them has the ID of #TestPointResults, when I define the display:inline; in my CSS stylesheet, it doesn't render, or add that style to my elements.

And why I am using grid_12 for the both of them, is because its an ajax call, that renders the partialview, and renders a view that has 2 divs, one for checkboxes, other for results.
Even if the TestPointResults is inline, it still doesn't display it inline.

I tried looking it with developer tools, it said it didn't have that property.
Can anyone help me with that or can you suggest another method, how I can keep 2 div elements parallel in a grid_12 class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how I can do it, I just set the first div with float:left; and the right one stays display:inline;. 
Works as I needed :)